# Why package installation with yum show wrong source repository?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, repository

I have a brand new CentOS 7 VM. Right after a global `yum -y update` I'm trying to install additional packages, for instance `net-snmp`.

**Package**

net-snmp               1:5.7.2-33.el7_5.2              (updates)

**Dependencies**

1. lm_sensors-libs        3.4.0-4.20160601gitf9185e5.el7  (base)
2. net-snmp-agent-libs    1:5.7.2-33.el7_5.2              (updates)
3. net-snmp-libs          1:5.7.2-33.el7_5.2              (updates)
4. perl-Data-Dumper       2.145-3.el7                     (base)

I don't understand why `net-snmp`, `net-snmp-agent-libs` and `net-snmp-libs` are referenced in "updates" repository, mainly because those ones do not appear in this repository: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/

Forcing "base" repository with `yum install net-snmp --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=base` shows a different version for net-snmp (which is logical) and all dependencies belong to the "base" repository:

**Package**

net-snmp               1:5.7.2-32.el7_5.2              (base)

**Dependencies**

1. lm_sensors-libs        3.4.0-4.20160601gitf9185e5.el7  (base)
2. net-snmp-agent-libs    1:5.7.2-32.el7_5.2              (base)
3. net-snmp-libs          1:5.7.2-32.el7_5.2              (base)
4. perl-Data-Dumper       2.145-3.el7                     (base)

Why and how to fix this issue and make yum query the relevant repository to install `net-snmp` package and its dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The [mirror link you posted](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/) is for CentOS 7.6.1810, but your current YUM repositories seem to be pointing to [CentOS 7.5.1804](http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/updates/x86_64/Packages/).  The current version of `net-snmp` from the CentOS 7.6 base repository would be `5.7.2-37`.

Possible issues are your YUM repository configurations are pinned to a specific version of CentOS, or your configured repositories have not been updated to the current CentOS version yet.  Cannot know for sure without seeing the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo`